# Can I find the base version of the *.patch file?

Tags: linux-kernel, diff, patch

I see https://patchwork.kernel.org/.
I have an old question.
Various *.patch files for the linux kernel are available on the Internet.
However, I can not tell which kernel version I created the patch file with.

For example, there is https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6509121/.
At the bottom of the page is a patch.
Can I find out which Kernel version or git version patch file this patch contains?
I wondered about https://patchwork.kernel.org/ or any other source code.
What rules are there?
Or should anyone try to apply it with patch files?

Comment: **TL;DR**: it's near to impossible. Long story... Patchwork is a helper service for Linux kernel developers to review and apply the contributions. It's not designed for users. Though if you invest a lot of time into this, you will understand this whole process and answer to your question becomes clear.

Comment: @0andriy I need to understand the kernel development process.
Thank you.